# Fast query to load specific data column

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have this output format for kits result counting:

```
   $out = array(
            'in progress' => 0,
            're-testing' => 0,
            'rejected' => 0,
            'negative' => 0,
            'positive' => 0,
            'inconclusive' => 0,
            'failed' => 0,
            'tested' => 0,
            'available' => 0,
            'total' => 0
        );
```

I implemented a loop to query in the kits and then check for corrispondence in result value, like that:

```
$kits = Kit::where('customerId', Auth::id())->get();
foreach ($kits as $kit) {
    if($kit->result !== '' && isset($out[$kit->result])){
        ++$out[$kit->result];
        ++$out['tested'];
    }
    if($kit->status == 'accepted' && !$kit->result){
        ++$out['in progress'];
    }
    ++$out['total'];
}
```

unfortunately this solution is very slow. Do you have any suggestions for how to do that? thanks.

EDIT: Is slow because there are too many items.

Comment: What do you mean by the solution is very slow? Is it on the query side or on the iteration of the objects?

Comment: The fastest way is almost definitely to put the logic into a single SQL query and let the database do it on your behalf. But if that's not an option, you are going to have to define "slow" and also provide some timings for various parts of the code. Is it the `where` that is slow, or the loop? How many items are in the loop?

Comment: @hppycoder  is slow because there are many kits in the database. How can I implement is a single query?

Comment: Great, then this isn't so much as a PHP question as it is a MySQL one then? What is your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

First you are querying with a condition `customerId`, so add an index to `customerId` field will improve query performance a lot.

Then you don't have to count the total, you can use `count()`.

```
$out['total'] = Kit::where('customerId', auth()->id())->count();
```

The part where you count the group of results `++$out[$kit->result];` looks like can be done with `groupBy()`

```
$kits = Kit::where('customerId', auth()->id())
    ->groupBy('result')
    ->select('result', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as no'))
    ->get();
```

Then for each result that you want to count, you can look up with `firstWhere()`.

```
$out['positive'] = $kits->firstWhere('result', 'positive')->no;
$out['negative'] = $kits->firstWhere('result', 'negative')->no;
...
```

`$out['tested']` is just the sum of all count.

```
$out['tested'] = $out['positive'] + $out['negative'] +...
```

And need another query for `$out['in progress']`

```
$out['in progress'] = Kit::where('customerId', auth()->id())
    ->where('status', 'accepted')
    ->whereNotNull('result')
    ->where('result', '!=', '')
    ->count();
```